# java calculator without stack or arraylist

Tags: java, calculator, stringtokenizer

java calculator without stack or arraylist

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: Maybe it depends on what you are parsing, but I don't think limiting yourself to only 5 operands is a good thing.

Comment: What is some sample input? Will it be like `1 + 2` or `1 2 +`?

Comment: You say you are "not allowed to use stack or arraylist".  Does that mean that you are expected to _implement your own_ stack?  Does it mean you are expected to write a recursive method?  (i.e., implicitly using the call stack as a data stack) If neither of the above, then what _are_ you allowed to do?  You can't evaluate arbitrary, parenthesized expressions without a stack of some kind.

Comment: actually it is not a homework, but a sample included in a book. My assignment was to try one of those samples, and I chose this..

Comment: Oh yeah but I was "supposed to" put 5 operands though..

Comment: Yes I have to write a recursive method. But I totally messed up with it...

Comment: 1+2*4 might be a sample input.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try to write a method like `String simplify ( String expression )` that would take an expression string (e.g., "3^(2*(4-2))" and apply P.E.M.D.A.S. to determine the next operation, evaluate it, and return the simplified expression.

So,

```
 3^(2*(4-2))...
 3^(2*2)...
 3^(4)...
 81
```

Once you have that, you can call it in a `while` loop until the output is a simple number.

`simplify` would be a fair bit of coding, but it *is* a homework assignment after all, and I think it can be written using only the elements you listed (Double, String, StringTokenizer, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class calculator
{
   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       calculator otp = new calculator();
       String choice1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mathematical operations list:-\n1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division\n5.Modulus\n6.Square Root\n7.Exponent\n8.Pi\n9.Sine\n10.Cosine\n11.Tangent\nEnter the number of the mathematical operation of your choice");
       int choice = Integer.parseInt(choice1);
       if( choice == 1)
       {
           otp.Addition();
       }
       else if( choice == 2)
       {
           otp.Subtraction();
       }
       else if( choice == 3)
       {
           otp.Multiplication();
       }
       else if( choice == 4)
       {
           otp.Division();
       }
       else if( choice == 5)
       {
           otp.Modulus();
       }
       else if( choice == 6)
       {
           otp.Squareroot();
       }
       else if( choice == 7)
       {
           otp.Exponent();
       }
       else if( choice == 8)
       {
           otp.Pi();
       }
       else if( choice == 9)
       {
           otp.Sine();
       }
       else if( choice == 10)
       {
           otp.Cosine();
       }
       else if( choice == 11)
       {
           otp.Tangent();
       }
       else
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a number between 1 and 11 ","Info",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       }
   }
   public void Squareroot()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String sqrt1;
       sqrt1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number");
       double sqrt = Double.parseDouble(sqrt1);
       double ans = Math.sqrt(sqrt);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Addition()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String add11, add21;
       add11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
       add21 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");
       double add1 = Double.parseDouble(add11);
       double add2 = Double.parseDouble(add21);
       double ans = add1 + add2;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Subtraction()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String sub11, sub21;
       sub11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
       sub21 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");
       double sub1 = Double.parseDouble(sub11);
       double sub2 = Double.parseDouble(sub21);
       double ans = sub1 - sub2;
       double rev = sub2 - sub1;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reverse Answer: " + rev,"Reverse Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Multiplication()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String mul11, mul21;
       mul11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
       mul21 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");
       double mul1 = Double.parseDouble(mul11);
       double mul2 = Double.parseDouble(mul21);
       double ans = mul1 * mul2;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Division()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String div11, div21;
       div11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
       div21 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");
       double div1 = Double.parseDouble(div11);
       double div2 = Double.parseDouble(div21);
       double ans = div1 / div2;
       double rev = div2 / div1;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reverse Answer: " + rev,"Reverse Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Modulus()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String mod11, mod21;
       mod11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
       mod21 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");
       double mod1 = Double.parseDouble(mod11);
       double mod2 = Double.parseDouble(mod21);
       double ans = mod1 % mod2;
       double rev = mod2 % mod1;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reverse Answer: " + rev,"Reverse Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Exponent()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String exp11, exp21;
       exp11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the base number");
       exp21 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the power number");
       double exp1 = Double.parseDouble(exp11);
       double exp2 = Double.parseDouble(exp21);
       double ans = Math.pow(exp1 , exp2);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Sine()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String sin1;
       sin1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number");
       double sin = Double.parseDouble(sin1);
       double ans = Math.sin(sin);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Cosine()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String cos1;
       cos1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number");
       double cos = Double.parseDouble(cos1);
       double ans = Math.cos(cos);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
   public void Tangent()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String tan1;
       tan1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number");
       double tan = Double.parseDouble(tan1);
       double ans = Math.tan(tan);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
    public void Pi()throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String pi1;
       pi1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number");
       double pi = Double.parseDouble(pi1);
       double ans = Math.PI * pi;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer: " + ans,"Answer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is this?